# Is there any way to implement a NetSuite GL Lines Plugin using SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: plugins, netsuite, suitescript

Is there any way to implement a NetSuite GL Lines Plugin using SuiteScript 2.0?

This code doesn't work. When I try to create a plugin implementation in NetSuite, I select the script file but then it can't find any plugin types for me to select.

Would save me time if I could just do everything in SS2.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType plugintypeimpl
 */
define([ 'N/record', 'N/search' ],
    function(record, search) {
    return {
        customizeGlImpact : function(rec, standardLines, customLines, book) {
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are implementing SuiteGL.You should be doing it for now using SS1.0. There is no available module in SS2.0 that will allow you to access standard and custom lines. The available plug implementation can be used for custom SuiteApp. And maybe NS will be releasing equivalent SS2.0 for SuiteGL on their future release.